# Angular 2: Need help on approach to design model window wizard creation

Tags: angular, popup

I need to create a model window wizard with 4 steps in pop up format. If there is a some sample examples or design available please share it. Any recommended approach or design thoughts are welcome. I am new to angular.

Comment: Personnaly, i use dynamic loading component, with one component for each step of my wizard. After that you've got already design stepper module with some material themes (for example [covalent](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/steps) ). Angular material have planned to create one too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/) that has all bootstrap components to use with angular, you can use the Modal and the Tabs components.